# Manually calculations of MA(3) model differs from the results of Arima values using the forecast Package

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, moving-average

I have a time series that was fitted to a MA(3) using the forecast package in R.

```
Datos<-(111.02,109.42,108.95,112.26,101.35,92.51,117.83,97.71,125.96,89.84,104.73,106.86,113.31,111.74,99.04)
MoMA3<-Arima(Datos, order = c(0,0,3), method="CSS")
```

I used the definition of an MA(3) model to manually forecast the next value using the last 3 residuals of the fitted data and the estimated mean.

```
sum(MoMA3$coef[1:4]*c(MoMA3$residuals[15:13],1))
109.78
```

Nonetheless, my manually predicted value differs from the forecast function.

```
forecast(MoMA3, h=1)
106.86
```

Any ideas of what is possibly happening here?

thanks

Comment: The method based on the residuals from the conditional likelihood fit is not exact except in the limiting case that the sample size $n$ goes to infinity.  In contrast, `forecast::forecast` calls `predict.Arima` which computes exact finite history forecasts via Kalman filtering applied to the state-space representation of the model.

Comment: @JarleTufto, so is the difference in results due to `method="CSS"`?

Comment: @RichardHardy No, the difference is caused by the method based on the residuals (be it from a CSS or ML fit) not being exact.

Comment: @JarleTufto, how is it possible to have inexact residuals and exact forecasts from the same model? Is the model estimated differently when the goal is to obtain residuals than when the goal is to obtain forecasts? (I doubt that.)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is it possible to turn off the use of Kalman filter? So I get the same results. Thanks